# Reference un-managed class in C# Project

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged

I have problem using `zkemkeeper.dll` in C# project.
I have installed the sdk, copied files and run `regsrv32` as instructed. But I am stuck with the following error

```
The type or namespace name 'zkemkeeper' could not be found (are you missing a      using directive or an assembly reference?
```

The failing code line is

```
public zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass axCZKEM1 = new zkemkeeper.CZKEMClass();
```

`Dllimport` don't work, so any help ?

Comment: Assuming you added the `using zkemkeeper` or whatever its namespace is, right?

Comment: `using` is useless here, it yields the same error

Comment: Make sure the dll is 32-bit, and your project is targeting the same, also did you try simply adding the reference, then browsing to the dll?

Comment: It won't add the reference as the dll is unmanaged, it pops up an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the proprieties of your dll reference and set the value for Embed Interop Type to "False"